# Trying to delete two objects when placed next to eachother in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a Tetris-like game, where the user controls a block of a random color, and then drops that block to the bottom, where it locks in place and then spawns a new block at the top of the screen. I want to "clear" whenever two blocks of the same color are placed next to each other, and for whatever blocks were above those cleared blocks to move down, as if they were affected by gravity.

I've tried using the collision list to no avail.

Comment: You have to find adjoining blocks with the same color and to delete them from `copylist`. This has to be done, every time when a block reaches the bottom (e.g. in `chooseBlock`).

Comment: Alright, I might be able to think of an implementation, but what about moving blocks that are above deleted blocks down?

Comment: Of course you've to drop those blocks down, whose block below has gone. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find adjoining blocks with the same color and to delete them from `copylist`. This has to be done, every time when a block reaches the bottom (e.g. in `chooseBlock)`.

Find the indices of adjoining blocks and store them to a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). Note, in a set the indices are unique:

e.g.:

```py
adjoining = set()
for i in range(len(copylist)):
    for j in range(len(copylist)):
        if i == j or colorList[i] != colorList[j]:
            continue
        if (copylist[i][0] == copylist[j][0] and abs(copylist[i][1]-copylist[j][1]) == height) or \
           (copylist[i][1] == copylist[j][1] and abs(copylist[i][0]-copylist[j][0]) == width):
            adjoining.add(i)
            adjoining.add(j)
```

Create a new `copylist` and `colorList`, with contains only that elements, whose index is not contained in `adjoining`:

```py
copylist = [copylist[i] for i in range(len(copylist)) if i not in adjoining]
colorList = [colorList[i] for i in range(len(colorList)) if i not in adjoining]
```

At the end you've to find all the blocks which have to be dropped to the ground, because the block below was deleted.
Move down a block in [`not any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) block is below:

e.g.

```py
for i in range(len(copylist)):
    if copylist[i][1] >= 390:
        continue
    if not any([copylist[j] for j in range(len(copylist)) \
                if i != j and copylist[i][0] == copylist[j][0] and copylist[i][1] + height == copylist[j][1]]):
        copylist[i][1] += height
```

Do the algorithm in `chooseBlock` and repeat it until adjoining blocks are found:

```py
def chooseBlock():
    global player, copylist, colorList, colorChoice, blocksLeft
    #running list of blocks and their positions once placed
    copylist.append(player.copy())
    #running list of those blocks' colors
    colorList.append(colorChoice)
    #resetting player position
    player.y = 50 
    #choosing the color of the next block randomly from a list
    colorChoice = random.choice(colors)
    #subtracting 1 from the count of the blocks left to place after one is placed
    blocksLeft = blocksLeft - 1

    while True:
        adjoining = set()
        for i in range(len(copylist)):
            for j in range(len(copylist)):
                if i == j or colorList[i] != colorList[j]:
                    continue
                if (copylist[i][0] == copylist[j][0] and abs(copylist[i][1]-copylist[j][1]) == height) or \
                   (copylist[i][1] == copylist[j][1] and abs(copylist[i][0]-copylist[j][0]) == width):
                    adjoining.add(i)
                    adjoining.add(j)

        if not adjoining:
            break

        copylist = [copylist[i] for i in range(len(copylist)) if i not in adjoining]
        colorList = [colorList[i] for i in range(len(colorList)) if i not in adjoining]

    testmovedown = True
    while testmovedown:
        testmovedown = False
        for i in range(len(copylist)):
            if copylist[i][1] >= 390:
                continue
            if not any([copylist[j] for j in range(len(copylist)) \
                        if i != j and copylist[i][0] == copylist[j][0] and copylist[i][1] + height == copylist[j][1]]):
                copylist[i][1] += height
                testmovedown = True
```

[image]